# Database that use sql queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i run this but there's no data when i run it...how can i fix this problem ? any suggestion ?-MICROSOFT ACCESS

Using Microsoft Access (or any other DBMS tool), create the tables (using DDL SQL), and enter sample data (using DDL SQL or GUI). 5 records per table is enough. Use a suitable data type for each field. Make sure you create the relationship between tables, also using DDL SQL. Then, write DML SQL queries that answer the questions below (one query per question) and run them.

3. Find the names of pilots certified for some Boeing aircraft

Code so far:

```
SELECT distinct e.EmpName 
FROM employee e,aircraft a,certified c 
WHERE e.EmpID=c.EmpID 
AND c.AircraftID=a.AircraftID 
AND a.AircraftName='Boeing';
```

Comment: How about we start with providing some code you have tried so far? :)

Comment: Seems that whatever you're doing involves making a mistake of some kind.  You'll want to find and correct the mistake.  We might be able to help with that if you provide *any* information about the problem.

Comment: @David    SELECT distinct e.EmpName
 FROM employee e,aircraft a,certified c
 WHERE e.EmpID=c.EmpID
 AND c.AircraftID=a.AircraftID
AND a.AircraftName='Boeing';

Comment: @EdvinTenovim SELECT distinct e.EmpName
 FROM employee e,aircraft a,certified c
 WHERE e.EmpID=c.EmpID
 AND c.AircraftID=a.AircraftID
AND a.AircraftName='Boeing';

Comment: @Jaws: And?  What's the error?  In what way is this query failing?  What data have you confirmed to be present?  What is the structure of the tables?  What is the expected result of this query?  What is the actual result?

Comment: @David there's no data when i run it...how can i show u the problem..hemm...i don't even can upload the photo in here

Comment: "and enter sample data (using DDL SQL or GUI)"... maybe before selecting, insert may help... did you skip a section of your class? ;)

Comment: @Jaws: What happens when you `SELECT *` from each table individually?  Is there data?  Are the values compared in your `WHERE` clause *exact* in the tables?  Seriously, *we can't know what's wrong* without knowing anything about what you're doing.  We can't see your screen from here, nor are we talking to you from inside your computer.

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do is to start ONLY with the simplest possible select, and then add the conditions. In your case, I would start with:

```
SELECT distinct e.EmpName FROM employee e,aircraft a,certified c`
```

and see that there is some data. Then add the first condition (i.e. `WHERE e.EmpID=c.EmpID`), then the second, etc., and only and the end the `DISTINCT`. This way, you will see where the problem might be.

Also, be aware if the **case** (upper/lower) of the contents. If your database is case-sensitive and one field in a table is "Thisismydata" while in the other "THISISMYDATA", they will not match.